# In CrafterCMS, can engine handle case insensitive URLs?

Tags: url, content-management-system, crafter-cms

I was wondering if Crafter Engine could handle case insensitive urls such as `/hello-World` would be served the same as `/hello-world` ?

Thank you,

Nicolas

Comment: To be precise: it's regarding a crafter engine 2.5.x.

Answer (score 9):

By default, Crafter CMS's URLs are lowercase and Crafter Engine is case sensitive.

Your best choice is to front it with Apache HTTPd with a lower-casing rewrite rule. Something like this:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) ${lc:$1} [PT,L]`